# Performance tuning in Linux for a TCP based server application

Tags: performance, networking, network-programming

I have written an application that communicates over TCP using a proprietary protocol. I have a test client that starts a thousand threads that each make requests from the client, and I noticed I can only get about 100 requests/second, even with fairly simple operations. These requests are all coming from the same client so that might be relevant.

I'm trying to understand how I can make things faster. I've read a bit about performance tuning in this area, but I'm trying to understand what I need to understand to performance tune network applications like this. Where should I start? What linux settings do I need to override, and how do I do it?

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using asynchronous methods to do the test instead of trying to spawn lots of threads. Each time one thread stops and other starts on the same cpu core, aka. [context switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), there can be a very significant overhead. If you want a quick example of networking using asynchronous methods check out [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net) and look at how the NetworkComms.ConnectionListenModeUseSync property is used [here](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/987ff2245685/NetworkCommsDotNet/NetworkComms.cs). Obviously if you're running in linux you would have to use mono to run networkComms.net.

Answer (score -1):

Play around with the **Sysctls** and **Socket Options** of the TCP stack: [man tcp(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/tcp). E.g. you can change the send and receive buffer of tcp or switch **NO_DELAY** on. Actually to tune the TCP stack itself you should know how TCP works. Things like slow start, congestion control, congestion window etc. But this is related to the transmitting/receiving performance and the buffers maybe with your process handling.

Comment: my theory about the 100 requests/second thing is that it's limiting me to 128 connections from one host (localhost) so the others are getting queued/rejected and retrying. When I just open one connection but do a lot of data back-and-forth i get about 2ms per request, which is plenty good enough (plus time on the wire)

Comment: have done some TCP related learning so i get the general idea of its congestion management and reliability features, i'm mainly trying to understand how to implement specific optimizations on the server (linux) side, since I imagine on the client (windows) side there's not much i can do what that steaming pile of dogshit

Comment: @Jason you shouldn't mess with most of this stuff. In fact, as you are getting acceptable performance over a single link, I cannot imagine what the point of interfering with slow start, congestion control etc could possibly be, or why this poster is even talking about it. Large socket send and receive buffers are always a good idea. But it seems to me that you have a concurrency problem in your code, not a networking problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to Understand the following Linux utility [Command](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Si0qwjhFbZ4)

uptime - Tell how long the system has been running.

uptime gives a one line display of the following information. The current time, how long the system has been running, how many users are currently logged on, and the system load averages for the past 1, 5, and 15 minutes.

top provides an ongoing look at processor activity in real time. It displays a listing of the most CPU-intensive tasks on the system, and can provide an interactive interface for manipulating processes

The mpstat command writes to standard output activities for each available processor, processor 0 being the first one. Global average activities among all processors are also reported. The mpstat command can be used both on SMP and UP machines, but in the latter, only global average activities will be printed. If no activity has been selected, then the default report is the CPU utilization report.

iostat - The  iostat  command  is used for monitoring system input/output device
       loading by observing the time the devices are  active  in  relation  to
       their average transfer rates.

vmstat reports information about processes, memory, paging, block IO, traps, and cpu activity. The first report produced gives averages since the last reboot

free - display information about free and used memory on the system

ping : ping uses the ICMP protocol's mandatory ECHO_REQUEST datagram to elicit an ICMP ECHO_RESPONSE from a host or gateway

Dstat allows you to view all of your system resources instantly, you can eg. compare disk usage in combination with interrupts from your IDE controller, or compare the network bandwidth numbers directly with the disk throughput (in the same interval)

Then you need to know how TCP protocol work, Learn how to identify the Network [Latency](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-wLx7p5qCI), where is the Problem, is the problem with ACK,SYCN,ACK SYC, DATA, RELEASE

Comment: He's asking how to make it faster, not how to measure the slowness. He seems to be already aware of that. I don't know what your last paragraph is supposed to mean. Why would latency be associated with *one* of SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK, etc (to correct your terminology)?